# In App Purchase: Sign in required [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I unfortunately typed my real **production account** to purchase an IAP in the **sandbox environment**.

Since then, I am getting annoying alerts the whole day, which constantly ask me to sign in to my account.

The account textfield is **prefilled** with my production account, so there is no way to fill in a new sandbox account.

This happens with the **production version** from the app store and the **debug version**. If deleted, it doesn't appear anymore.

Does anyone know what to do to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by completely wiping my iPhone, without restoring my data from a backup. Sad.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and worked around without factory default doing this.

I force closed all app, then loged out of iTune and App store only.  Rebooted the phone. After restart, make sure to double check if it still loged out of iTune and App store before starting the app. Once the app has been started without user logged in it fixed the issue and i was able to log back Apple account’

Comment: Thank you. I‘ll try it the next time. (Hopefully not)